# Set, get Authentication Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, guard

I want to check user logging by Auth:
My code (save email, password to Auth):

```
$userdata = array(
                'email'      => $email,
                'password'      => $password
            );
if(Auth::attempt($userdata))
{
      $this->auth->attempt($userdata);
      //$user = User::where('email',$email)->first();
      //Auth::login($user);           
      return redirect('admin');
}
```

When i ran this code, it take me to admin page.
In admin page, i want to show auth (for test auth can be save or not), like this:

```
return var_dump(Auth->user());
```

for: __construct:

```
protected $auth;
public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return var_dump($this->auth->user());        
}
```

I get NULL value. What is my problem? How can solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Auth::user()` instead of `Auth->user()`.

Comment: I used return var_dump(Auth->user()); in if(Auth::attempt($userdata)){....}. It work. by the way, I use Auth::user() instead of Auth->user(), it also return null.